# Finishing activity from static method

Tags: android, static, activity-finish

I would like to do a static method in a class for finishing an activity. I mean something like this :
activity A , activity B , activity C,  class ActivitiesKiller.
Class ActivitiesKiller has a static method for finishing the activity A, B or C.

An example:
My runnig class is B and I want to finish activity A, so I will call:

```
ActivitiesKiller.activityKiller(A);
```

Is that possible?.
Thanks in advanced

I´m doing something like this,  but It doesn´t work.

```
public class ActivitiesKiller {
 //.....

public static void activityKiller(Activity activity){ 
activity.finish();}


}
```

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea, and is possible only if you make a static reference to the Activities, which you shouldn't do, because it can cause memory leaks.

Comment: Maybe it's better to explain what you want to achieve and we can help, storing `Activity` in static is a bad idea, like Zhuinden said.

Comment: @Wakim is just curiosity I´m learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it doesn't sound like a good idea, what you would need to do is to make a static reference to the activities on creation, and null them on destruction.

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity
{
    public static Activity self;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
    {
       super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
       self = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
       super.onDestroy();
       self = null;
    }
}
```

And then you would need to do the following

```
public class ActivitiesKiller 
{
    public static void activityKiller(Activity activity)
    { 
        if(activity != null)
        {
            activity.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Which you would call as

```
ActivitiesKiller.activityKiller(ActivityA.self);
```